# Trigger multi-events

Tags: triggers, jquery

Can I trigger multi events in trigger() or chain them in JQuery!? E.g:

```
$(element).trigger('event1 event2 event3');
```

or

```
$(element).trigger('event1').trigger('event2');
```

or

```
$(element).trigger('event1');
$(element).trigger('event2');
```

Comment: I'm sure the lastest jQuery supports event queuing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As other answers note, the best *built-in* method is:

```
$(element).trigger('event1').trigger('event2');
```

However, I find that if you're doing this all over the place, a simple plugin cleans it up quite nicely, allowing the space-separated syntax (like [other](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) [methods](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)).  Here's a quick example of such a plugin:

```
$.fn.triggerAll = function(events) {
    if(!events) return this; //don't blow up if .triggerAll() without params
    var self = this;         //keep a reference
    $.each(events.split(" "), function(i, e) { self.trigger(e); });
    return this;
};
```

Then you can call it with space-separated event names, like this:

```
$(element).triggerAll('event1 event2 event3');
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/4Hzeh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(element).trigger('event1 event2 event3');
```

is not supported.

```
(element).trigger('event1').trigger('event2');
```

is optimal over

```
$(element).trigger('event1');
$(element).trigger('event2');
```

as you are not rebuilding the jQuery object containing $(element) each time you trigger an event.