# How to execute a function after one event is triggered?

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown menu (not the select menu available in HTML but a custom one based on a **div which shows another div**) that dynamically loads when it's clicked.
Then the user can select some option from it.

Now, I want to be able to trigger some menu option **programmatically**.
So basically:

```
$("#menu").trigger("click"); // open the menu
$("#menu").find("....").click(); // find the desired option in the menu who's just been loaded after "artificial" click.
```

The problem here is that jQuery doesn't trigger the first click immediately.
Indeed I tried by **console.log()** and no object is found (**prevObject** is printed).
If I set a **timeout** it works instead but of course this is just a "hopefully-it-works" workaround.

The solution would be kind of:

```
trigger("click, function(){ 
   // second trigger here
});
```

Any clue?

Comment: Based on this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5050598/2048391 it looks like you could chain those trigger events; so I guess you could get it working that way.

Comment: Reading back... did you wrap your code in a `$(document).ready()` before? That first one (I read `#menu` is not dynamic but is there at doc ready) should really trigger a click.

Comment: the event handler is attached after the DOM's been fully loaded since I'm adding the handler within the controller of an AngularJS application. thus the view (.html) is loaded, then the controller is executed and within it the handler.
#menu itself (I mean, the button to show the menu) is there since the beginning, what is dynamically loaded is the CONTENT of the menu.
Now I will try the solution from your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the content is loaded dynamically, I think you'd need a delegated event :

```
$(document).on('click', '#menu', function() {

$(this).find("....").trigger('click');
});
```

Or something like it, at least (a fiddle or a bit more code would be helpful)...

Edit - there must a dozen ways to approach this, if you define what should happen step by step (adding dynamic content then binding the click event on it) it looks like you shouldn't even need a delegated event. But here's a way to do it in one chain of methods (first bit add some content) :

```
$('#menu').one('click', function() {
$('<div id="content"></div>').appendTo('#menu');
});

$('#menu').on('click', '#content', function() {
console.log('new content clicked');
});

$('#menu').trigger('click').find('#content').trigger('click');
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPYgoZ?editors=001

My conclusion, unless `#menu` is added dynamically as well one shouldn't need to delegate the event. Chaining methods should work... the delegation would on be needed to *detect*  the trigger of the new element. Also tried if external/larger content influences anything but that is not the case.

Only thing I got from that is an alternative line of code in case you'd want to wait for the content to be loaded before the click is triggered :

```
$('#menu').trigger('click').find('#content').on('load', function() {$(this).trigger('click')});
```

Comment: Cheers, I'll see if I can refine it a bit through some testing (and a live example).

Comment: ok, I'll try it right now.
Can you just please clarify what's the difference between delegation and chain? they looks like the same thing

Comment: In practice chaining is active and delegation is passive. With the first one you can apply several methods to an element without the need to call the object again each time. You can just put them all in a row, like the last line in the answer. This has the `trigger`, `find` and `on` methods chained. Delegation is defined by *listening* to events. The difference with a normal/direct event listener is that delegation can 'catch' events on elements that were created dynamically. Here it would only be needed if you want to act on a click on any new element. Hope that helps a bit.

Answer (score 0):

try using .on('click', function ()) instead of on click on the inner clicks of the menu.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated (same page).

Comment: I just edited the answer for the official replacement of .live